# What is the best way to use API and hide responses

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I have a SPA website built over Laravel and Vue.

I am using axios to get the responses and all working fine.

The most of the data is vendor, categories and products and nothing sensitive in it however products has some data which I need to use in frontend however I don't want my competitors to get hold on to that data.

How to do I go about that? so I get the data but it's hidden as well?

So I thought may be I encrypt it and then decrypt it but not sure if that's the right approach

```
{

"Products": [
    {
        "ID": 9950,
        "VID": 114,
        "Name": "TBH Special Burger ",
        "Category": 224,
        "Description": "",
        "Image": "",
        "Price": "250",
        "DisplayPrice": 0,
        "DealPrice": 0,
        "Percentage": "15",
        "Cust_Percentage": "0.00",
        "DateTime": "2018-10-08 19:03:40",
    },
],
}
```

In above response only percentage related data is I am trying to secure.

Comment: You could add a private endpoint just for your SPA that serves the percentage, and have the public endpoint serve a null value for consistency. An alternative would be to configure something dynamic for first party users(users of your SPA) and swap resources depending on the configuration; this way you still only need one endpoint.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is logically impossible

Comment: There's no way at all. All you can do is to make the use of API apart from the website harder, to the point it would be impractical to steal data on a constant basis.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport).

> Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes.

With `Passport`, only authenticated users can access your data via API.
Read the documentation in the link above and give it a try.

If non authenticated users access your api by typing the url in his browser, this is the response that he will get:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated"
}
```

**Consuming Your API With JavaScript**

Laravel provides a *middleware* that allow you to consume your api from your JS app. From the docs:

> Typically, if you want to consume your API from your JavaScript application, you would need to manually send an access token to the application and pass it with each request to your application. However, Passport includes a middleware that can handle this for you. All you need to do is add the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to your web middleware group in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:
>
> ```php
> 'web' => [
>    // Other middleware...
>    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
> ],
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Mateus, thanks for your reply and this will help me in something else I want to achieve. However at this stage the website is public and where I want anyone to access it there only couple of fields I want to transfer from laravel (Backend) to Vue (Frontend) secretly without anyone else able to see that.

Comment: Is your frontend application bundled with laravel or in a separate project?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, they are bundled together.

Comment: If they are bundled, my answer is exactly what you are looking for. You can't hide fields from the api response and still using it with VueJS.  The best way to solve this, is using Laravel passport to add api authentication. Using the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware, you don't need to worry about pass tokens with every single request, and it will make your job much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **API Resources** to specify witch fields you would like to show in response
take look to docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for your reply the thing is I do want that fields however I want it to be hidden at the same time. I don't know if I am not specifying it clearly

Comment: ok, I am checking but not sure if I understand this. The only thing I found relevant is secret value with conditional formatting but that won't solve my problem

Comment: `ApiResources` are not useful here since it works like a transformation layer between your model and the JSON response return to your application user.